# How to sync a JS class to a component's state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completing a technical challenge and came across a scenario I never had to deal with before.

I am asked to code up a shopping cart that has a UI that represents basic checkout data like order total, current items in cart, etc.

One of the requirements states I need to implement a Checkout class **that can be instantiated**:

```
const checkout = new Checkout();
```

And I should be able to obtain basic info from it like:

```
const total = checkout.total();
```

And add items to the cart through it:

```
checkout.add(product.id);
```

What makes this a tricky thing to solve is that I can't think of a clean "DRY" way of implementing it into the UI. This is mainly because any updates in the checkout class will not trigger any re-renders since it's not part of the state. I would usually use state variables for this.

I tried binding state variables to parameters in the checkout class like:

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState();
useEffect(()=>{
   setTotal(checkout.total)
}, [checkout.total])
```

But `checkout.total` is **only the reference to the method**, so it never changes so I do not get the binding I want.

Trying out other stuff I managed to put together a "solution" but I question whether it is a good pattern.

I basically pass a callback to the checkout class which is called whenever the cart is updated. The callback is a state variable's setter, so:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState<string[]>(checkout.cart);
checkout.callback = setCart;
```

Then inside the add method:

```
add(productId) {
   // Some code...
   this.callback([...this.cart]);
}
```

What this grants is that the `cart` state variable is updated whenever the `checkout` class has changes in its parameters. So it fires a rerender on the Cart component and all of its children that have props being passed down. Therefore I get a synced UI.

The thing is I kind of don't need the cart variable other than for forcing re-renders. I can get the cart info directly from the `checkout` class which is what I do. But for it to be reflected in the UI I need some state variable to be updated. It could even be a counter, I only went for `cart` instead of a counter to make it more coherent I guess.

Am I overcomplicating things here? Is there a pattern I am missing that is used for this scenarios? How does one usually interact with an instantiated class and ensures the UI is somehow updated from changes to the class?

EDIT (adding missing info):
The Checkout class needs to implement the following interface:

```
interface Checkout {
  // ...
  // Some non relevant properties methods
  // ...
  add(id: number): this;
}
```

So it is explicitly asked that the `add` method returns `this` (in order to allow function chaining).

Answer (score 5):

**mixing of patterns**

Using OOP instances with methods that mutate internal state will prevent observation of a state change -

```js
const a = new Checkout()
const b = a                     // b is *same* state
console.log(a.count)            // 0
a.add(item)
console.log(a.count)            // 1
console.log(a == b)             // true
console.log(a.count == b.count) // true
```

React is a functional-oriented pattern and uses complimentary ideas like [immutability](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data). Immutable object methods will create *new* data instead of mutating *existing* state -

```js
const a = new Checkout() 
const b = a.add(item)           // b is *new* state
console.log(a.count)            // 0
console.log(b.count)            // 1
console.log(a == b)             // false
console.log(a.count == b.count) // false
```

In this way, `a == b` is `false` which effectively sends the signal to redraw this component. So we need a *immutable* `Checkout` class, where methods return new state instead of mutating existing state -

```js
// Checkout.js

class Checkout {
  constructor(items = []) {
    this.items = items
  }
  add(item) {
    return new Checkout([...this.items, item]) // new state, no mutation
  }
  get count() {
    return this.items.length // computed state, no mutation
  }
  get total() {
    return this.items.reduce((t, i) => t + i.price, 0) // computed, no mutation
  }
}

export default Checkout
```

**demo app**

Let's make a quick app. You can click the  and  buttons to add items to the cart. The app will show the correct `count` and `total` as well as the individual items -

| *App component preview* |
| --- |
| [image: preview] |

Now "syncing" the class to the component is just using ordinary React pattern. Use your class and methods directly in your componenets -

```js
import Checkout from "./Checkout.js"
import Cart from "./Cart.js"

function App({ products = [] }) {
  const [checkout, setCheckout] = React.useState(new Checkout)
  const addItem = item => event =>
    setCheckout(checkout.add(item))
  return <div>
    {products.map(p =>
      <button key={p.name} onClick={addItem(p)}>{p.name}</button>
    )}
    <b>{checkout.count} items for {money(checkout.total)}</b>
    <Cart checkout={checkout} />
  </div>
}

const data =
  [{name: "", price: 5}, {name: "", price: 3}]

const money = f =>
  new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(f)
```

A simple `Cart` component uses `JSON.stringify` to quickly visualize each item -

```js
// Cart.js

function Cart({ checkout }) {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(checkout, null, 2)}</pre>
}

export default Cart
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
class Checkout {
  constructor(items = []) {
    this.items = items
  }
  add(item) {
    return new Checkout([...this.items, item])
  }
  get count() {
    return this.items.length
  }
  get total() {
    return this.items.reduce((t, i) => t + i.price, 0)
  }
}

function App({ products = [] }) {
  const [checkout, setCheckout] = React.useState(new Checkout)
  const addItem = item => event =>
    setCheckout(checkout.add(item))
  return <div>
    {products.map(p =>
      <button key={p.name} onClick={addItem(p)}>{p.name}</button>
    )}
    <b>{checkout.count} items for {money(checkout.total)}</b>
    <Cart checkout={checkout} />
  </div>
}

const money = f =>
  new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(f)
  
function Cart({ checkout }) {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(checkout, null, 2)}</pre>
}

const data = [{name: "", price: 5}, {name: "", price: 3}]

ReactDOM.render(<App products={data} />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This has been extremely helpful and makes plenty of sense at a first glance. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @JuanChaher happy to hear it. If you have follow up questions, don't be shy

Comment: Just updated the question under "EDIT". Basically I need to explicitly return "this" from the add method. If I were to return a new instance of the Checkout class, the pipeline to push the code will fail so it is probably a requirement of the assesment. Do you still see your proposed pattern valid? Or should Nekrodev one's make more sense?

Comment: If you cannot make your data type immutable, then yes Nekrodev has a good solution. And good to be aware of this fundamental difference. It should be helpful when you get to make these choices on your own.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, looks like you need to share the state. The first solution that came to my mind is just to use the Class component. You can use force rerender while you need and write more custom logic without `useEffect` hacks.

The second solution is more clear IMO. It uses an Observer pattern. You need to add a subscription to your Checkout class. So basically.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const subscription = (newState) => setState(newState)
 const instance = new Checkout()
 instance.subcribe(subscription)
 return () => instance.unsubcribe(subscription)
}, [setState])
```

Since setState is immutable, this hook will be run only once.

Comment: the `unsubscribe` should be declared in a nullary return function, `return () => instance.unsubscribe(subscription)` so that it only runs when the component unmounts

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct, you need somehow to start re-render to sync state of checkout object and state of a component.

E.g. you may do it by context and force update (in case if you do not want to duplicate data in object and state):

```js
const CheckoutContext = React.createContext();

const checkout = new Checkout();

const CheckoutProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // init force update, just to start re-render
  const [ignored, forceUpdate] = React.useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);
  
  const add = (a) => {
    checkout.add(a);
    forceUpdate();
  };

  const total = checkout.total();

  const value = { add, total };

  return (
    <CheckoutContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </CheckoutContext.Provider>
  );
};


const Child = () => {
  const v = React.useContext(CheckoutContext);
  console.log(v.total);
  return <button onClick={() => v.add(100)}>Click</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CheckoutProvider>
        <Child />
      </CheckoutProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of extra code. OP specifically wanted a way to reduce the amount of unnecessary code.

Comment: I think that @Juan wants to avoid data duplication in object and component state

Comment: "The thing is I kind of don't need the cart variable other than for forcing re-renders." What makes `ignored` and `forceUpdate` different from `cart` in this regard?

Comment: As I said the idea was correct, you anyway need to re-render somehow. I show a possible solution without passing a callback and if you need to have access to checkout object in several components

Answer (score 2):

You can make a Cart class that allows for observers to be notified when something important happens. To make it available for the react components, provide an instance of it with a context, and use a stateful hook to notify components by setting the state through the observer function.

Here we go:
First, we need a Cart class that notifies observers when something happens

```
export class Cart {
  constructor() {
    this.products = [];
    this.subscribers = new Set();
  }
  subscribe = (notifyMe) => {
    this.subscribers.add(notifyMe);
  };
  unSubscribe = (notifyMe) => {
    this.subscribers.delete(notifyMe);
  };
  addToCart = (product) => {
    this.products = [...this.products, product];
    this.notify();
  };
  removeFromCart = (product) => {
    this.products = this.products.filter(product);
    this.notify();
  };
  notify = () => {
    this.subscribers.forEach((n) => n(this.products));
  };
}
```

We will expose this through the react tree with a context, so lets make one

```
const CartContext = React.createContext();

export const CartProvider = ({ children, cart }) => {
  return <CartContext.Provider value={cart}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>;
};
```

Now for the trick! A hook that will update its state using the carts observer pattern, thereby notifying the component that uses it.

```
export const useCart = () => {
  const cart = React.useContext(CartContext);
  const [content, r] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const notify = (productsInCart) => r(productsInCart);
    cart.subscribe(notify);
    cart.notify();
    return () => cart.unSubscribe(notify);
  }, [cart, r]);
  return {
    addToCart: cart.addToCart,
    removeFromCart: cart.removeFromCart,
    content
  };
};
```

Note that it can be worth to update after subscribing.

Now we have our library set up, we can make some components. So here's where we instantiate the Cart class. We make a new Cart, and let the provider provide that *instance*

```
const cart = new Cart();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CartProvider cart={cart}>
        <CartCounter />
        <h1>Welcome to the shop</h1>
        <h2>start putting stuff in the cart!</h2>
        <Catalog />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            // this will still notify components
            cart.addToCart({ foo: "bar" });
          }}
        >
          add product by directly manipulating class instance
        </button>
      </CartProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here are the other components

```
const Catalog = () => {
  const getProducts = async () =>
    await fetch(
      "https://random-data-api.com/api/commerce/random_commerce?size=6"
    ).then((r) => r.json());
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getProducts().then(setProducts);
  }, []);

  if (!products) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ul
      style={{
        listStyle: "none",
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "50% 50%"
      }}
    >
      {products.map((product) => (
        <Item key={product.uid} product={product} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

const Item = ({ product }) => {
  const { addToCart } = useCart();
  const addProductToCart = () => addToCart(product);
  return (
    <li>
      <article
        style={{
          maxWidth: 200,
          border: "1px solid black",
          margin: 10,
          padding: 10
        }}
      >
        <h4>{product.product_name}</h4>
        <div>
          <div>$ {product.price}</div>
          <button onClick={addProductToCart}>add to cart</button>
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
  );
};

const CartCounter = () => {
  const { content } = useCart();
  return <div>items in cart: {content?.length || 0}</div>;
};
```

This can be a pretty handy pattern, and can be taken pretty far (e.g. React Query works like this).

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-instance-sn6rwv?file=/src/App.js:644-1873)

Comment: Nice explanation, but I think there are a couple of mistakes:
1- You don't need to pass the cart instance through the context, since you declared it outside your *React Component*, hence it's already in scope.
2- Wouldn't it be more correct to use the `useCart` hook just on top of the `Catalogue` render and not in each single `Item` Component, to avoid to multiply subscriptions that would be useless in that case, you can then pass the methods and the *content* down with *context*.

Comment: 1) The cart instance is not exported from that module, so it is not in scope. Also, this way we can pass it around without having global variables strewn about the place, or deciding for the consumer of our cart lib how many carts they can have.

2) Yes that is possible, but then refactoring might become more cumbersome and involve some prop drilling. I prefer to leverage the React context feature that the hooks will correspond the the closest context in the tree. As for the `Item`s, they unsubscribe on unmounting anyway, so there are no useless subscriptions.

Comment: 1) Yeah I exaggerated calling them "mistakes" but I mean it can be simply exported without the need using a context just for that, it's potentially just in context. Matter of choice I guess.
2) I'm not sure it'd involve props drilling, I'd just pass those methods to the Cart Provider. 
If you let each item consume that custom hook, they are going to unsubscribe on unmount but if you have 1000 items, you are going to have anyway 1000 useless subscriptions functions that run everytime you interact with the cart or not ?

Comment: Talk to your designer about mounting 1000 products in a single view :D

But I totally get your point, it's a valid critizism. It could absolutely be cleaner and less "magic" to pass a "onAddToCart" prop to each item or something like that like you say.

Answer (score 0):

I read with interest most of the answers, and I found them pretty explicative and comprehensive, especially the extensive example of the observer pattern.
I used the same approach to handle a similar need, without having to implement all the pattern and it makes use of the 'EventEmitter' class.
This way you can subscribe your React UI to several different type of events, olle's example would become something like this:

```js
export class Cart extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.products = [];
  }
  addToCart = (product) => {
    this.products = [...this.products, product];
    this.emit("CART_UPDATE", this.products)
  };
  removeFromCart = (product) => {
    this.products = this.products.filter(product);
    this.emit("CART_UPDATE", this.products)
  };
}
```

And in `React` you'd just need a custom hook or just an `effect` placed on top where you can place your event listeners:

```js
export default function App() {

  const cartRef = useRef(new Cart())
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{

    const cart = cartRef.current
    cart.on("CART_UPDATE", setItems)

    return () => cart.removeListener("CART_UPDATE", setItems)
  }, []) // 
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>{items.map(it => item.id)}</div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            // this will still notify components
            cart.addToCart({ id: "bar" });
          }}
        >
          add product by directly manipulating class instance
        </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it is perfectly reasonable to send a callback to the object and then call that callback when it is needed. If you don't want to add any unnecessary data, then don't:

```
add(productId) {
  // Some code...
  this.callback();
}
```

---

```
checkout.callback = () => {
  setTotal(checkout.total);
}
```